# update python dictonary in MySQL database

Tags: python, mysql, dictionary, sql-update

```
mail_data = {
  "20220406155259_Dhaval_sutaria": [
    {
      "complainant_name": "Dhaval sutaria",
      "created_date": "2023-04-06 14:52:57",
      "message": "hey Dhaval",
      "updated_date": "2023-04-13 10:42:08",
      "email": "sutariya@gmail.com",
      "attachement": 2
    },
    {
      "complainant_name": "Adnjf with Sulbactum",
      "strength": "2g/1g Powder for injection",
      "email": "dhaval@gmail.com",
      "message": "nvdfdbndgb;dm",
      "case_id": "20230406145257_dhaval_sutaria",
      "created_date": "2023-04-06 14:52:57",
      "updated_date": "2023-04-13 10:42:08"
    }
    # .....
  ]
}
```

`mail_data['20230406145257_dhaval_sutaria'][0]` same table update in first record

`mail_data['20230406145257_dhaval_sutaria'][1]` same table update in second record

`mail_data['20230406145257_dhaval_sutaria'][2]` same table update in third record

continue....

want to update in this way in database. keys name are same in database table. so i'm not sure how update this dictionary

i am expecting for mail_data
`mail_data['20230406145257_dhaval_sutaria'][0]` same table update in first record whatever keys is present in dictionary it will find and update

`mail_data['20230406145257_dhaval_sutaria'][1]` same table update in second record whatever keys is present in dictionary it will find and update

like continue